# Extracting number from filename

Tags: shell, filenames, string, cut

I have a filename following this model:

```
 1.raw_bank_details_211.trg
 2.raw_bank_details_222.trg
```

I need to use the `cut` command in unix and cut the above string to obtain `211`  and `222` from the strings and echo the value.

I already used grep `grep -o -E '[0-9]+'`, I need an alternative to this.

Comment: *a filename* OR a string?

Comment: I advise not to (ab)use the word requirement. This is a pro-bono service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cut` is the wrong tool for that. To manipulate short strings such as file names, use the shell's string manipulation facilities whenever possible. All sh-type shells¹ (sh, dash, bash, ksh, zsh, …) have some basic string manipulation as part of variable substitution. See e.g. the [dash manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dash.1.html) under “parameter expansion”. You can remove the shortest/longest prefix/suffix that matches a pattern.

You want the last sequence of digits in the file name, so:

1. Determine the non-numeric suffix by stripping everything up to the last digit.
2. Remove that suffix.
3. Strip everything up to the last non-digit.

```
filename=1.raw_bank_details_211.trg
suffix="${filename##*[0-9]}"
number="${filename%"$suffix"}"
number="${number##*[!-0-9]}"
```

¹  <sub>Except some pre-POSIX Bourne shells, but you don't care about those.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

You would be better off using a standard text processing tool instead of a naive tool like `cut`.

Here are some ways:

---

With `awk`, getting the `_` or `.` separated second last field:

```
awk -F '[_.]' '{print $(NF-1)}' file.txt
```

---

`grep` with PCRE (`-P`):

```
grep -Po '\d+(?=[^_]*$)' file.txt
```

- `-o` only gets the matched portion
- `\d+` matches one or more digits
- The zero width positive lookahead, `(?=[^_]*$)`, ensures that no `_` is following till end of the line

---

With `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/.*_([[:digit:]]+).*/\1/' file.txt
```

- `.*_` matches everything upto last `_`
- `([[:digit:]]+)` matches the required digits and put in captured group
- `.*` matches the rest
- In the replacement, only the captured group, `\1`, is used

---

With `perl`, same logic to the `sed` one:

```
perl -pe 's/.*_(\d+).*/$1/' file.txt
```

---

If you must use `cut`, do it in two steps, first get the `_` separated 4th field and then get `.` separated 1st field:

```
cut -d_ -f4 file.txt | cut -d. -f1
```

This is not recommended as this requires the field numbers to be hardcoded.

---

If it were a string, i would do it using shell parameter expansion:

```
% str='1.raw_bank_details_211.trg'

% str=${str##*_} 

% echo "${str%%.*}"
211
```

You can still use a `while` construct and take each line into a variable and do this, but that would be slow for a large file. Also alternately you could use `_.` as the `IFS` and get the hardcoded field (like `cut`) instead if you want.

---

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt                          
1.raw_bank_details_211.trg
2.raw_bank_details_222.trg

% awk -F '[_.]' '{print $(NF-1)}' file.txt
211
222

% grep -Po '\d+(?=[^_]*$)' file.txt         
211
222

% sed -E 's/.*_([[:digit:]]+).*/\1/' file.txt
211
222

% perl -pe 's/.*_(\d+).*/$1/' file.txt 
211
222

% cut -d_ -f4 file.txt | cut -d. -f1
211
222
```